# Yellow bugs on my trees

Tags: pests

[image: fat yellow bugs][image: fat yellow bugs]

The past week I noticed swarms of flying insects around my house and on my trees at sunset. I initially thought those are some kind of bees or wasps, but since i don't see them are day time, I didn't pay too much attention.

I happened to be outside at sunset today and caught the sight of some of them flying close by. I realized these are not bees or wasps. I have not a clue what they are and it looks like they are flying everywhere and mating.

I am starting to worry if these bugs will harm my garden especially the fruit trees it is mating on.

What are these, if I need to get rid of them, what can I do without using pesticides?

Comment: Where in the world are you? That information may help identifying your bugs.

Comment: I live in Vancouver BC. I found what these are. European Chafer Beetles. I also found that the lava can potentially destroy my lawns. The best solution without pesticides is to apply Nematodes into my lawn around mid July so the lava will be eaten by the Nematodes.

Answer (score 1):

I found what these are. European Chafer Beetles. I also found that the lava can potentially destroy my lawns. The best solution without pesticides is to apply Nematodes into my lawn around mid July so the lava will be eaten by the Nematodes.

Here are the references 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_chafer

https://vancouver.ca/home-property-development/chafer-beetles.aspx

Comment: Spot on! Lucky you for noticing them now, because you'll be able to treat your grass in July this year...